# Parse Number Column to CGFloat

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

The issue I am having is that I'm using an image height stored in a Parse class column with a type of Number. I'm then taking that height number and using it to set the UITableview row height. The problem is that when I try to use the number column value, it returns an error saying the types don't match. I'm doing this in Objective C. How can I use the Number value for the row height? I'm pretty sure I need to convert the Number value to a CGFloat but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumber` has already provided options for you to do it.

I suggestion you read on the documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber).

excerpt from Apple doc:

`NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int, long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL.`

to answer your question.

you can use the `floatValue` to get a `CGFloat` from an NSNumber

example:

```
CGFloat myFloat = [number floatValue];
```